# ContentBuilder Views Component doesn't list Views with SEF URLs

Tags: url, form, sef, view

I'm using ContentBuilder Views plugin to display my forms results. It works just fine, the problem is that it only works with **NO** SEF URL's. And i really would like to use SEF URL's so my links would be much more user friendly, it wouldn't display those visually messed up links.

When I use SEF URL's, I try to access my page where data forms are and I get a `404 - Not found`, although, my other pages are working fine. Even the form page. This only happens with the data display page.

Anyone has any idea why does it stop working with SEF URL's?

Best regards.

Comment: Do you already have .htaccess on your site? Also, are you using third party SEF?

Comment: Yes, I already have .htaccess on my website and no, i'm not using 3rd party SEF, Im using SEF from Joomla default definitions

Comment: If everything else is fine, it might be an issue of ContentBuilder. So use their support.